# Find the ellipse which is tangent to a line at a certain point

Tags: analytic-geometry

I have this problem here which i just can't seem to solve:

Find the equation of the ellipse which is tangent to the line $y=-x+3$  and touches said line at the point $P(1,y).$
The ellipse has center in $O(0,0)$ and the major axis is parallel to the x or y axis.

I can't use derivatives to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX!There is no single ellipse which satisfies these conditions!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention it has center in O.

Comment: And you probably forgot to mention that the major axis is parallel either with the x-axis or with the y-axis, right?

Comment: Hint: Try to find the intersection between ellipse and line. You get a quadratic equation. If this quadratic equation has exactly one solution, you have a point where the line is tangent to the ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

A conic is centred at origin if and only if its equation is
$$ ax^2+2bxy+cy^2=1. $$
This conic is an ellipse if and only if it has no real asymptotes, i.e. ifthe quadratic polynomial $at^2+2bt+c$ has no real root. This means that
$$b^2<ac.$$

The conic is tangent to  the line $y=-x+3$ if and only if the quadratic equation obtained by elimination of $y$ between both equations has a double root, i.e. its discriminant is $0$.

Furthermore, it is tangent to the line at the given point (with abscissa $1$) if the double root is $1$.

All this results in a system of a linear and a quadratic equations with a constraint, in the coefficients $a,b,c$.